# How is long-distance optical communications coming along in space?

Tags: deep-space-network, optical-communication

I remember there was a test of optical communication and some data transfer from lunar orbit to earth, and I think the ISS uploaded (or *downloaded-up*? which is correct here?) a movie from earth.

In order to have the [internet on Mars](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/15539/12102) not end up to be [too expensive](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/15539/are-there-discussions-or-plans-for-extending-the-internet-into-space-beyond-eart?noredirect=1#comment40973_15539) and to extend the [Deep Space Network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NASA_Deep_Space_Network) (and [here](http://deepspace.jpl.nasa.gov/) and [DSNnow here](http://eyes.nasa.gov/dsn/dsn.html)) capability, optical seems to be a very important technology for the not-so-distant future.

Free space optical communications (no optical fiber) seems to be just made for space. With a wavelength of the order of 1 micron instead of  10 centimeters, transmission antenna can be smaller in diameter for the same gain. Receiving antennae can possibly be smaller - basically *something like* the kind of optical telescopes they use now for astrophotography - but that depends on nearby bright sources of light and data rate.

*Were these tests successful? Have there been other tests? What's coming next*?

Screenshot(s) of [Deep Space Network Now](http://eyes.nasa.gov/dsn/dsn.html)

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [European Data Relay System](http://m.esa.int/Our_Activities/Telecommunications_Integrated_Applications/EDRS/Overview) has recently begun testing. It's for getting data from Earth orbiting satellites down to the ground quickly, without waiting for the satellite to pass over a base station.

Claimed data rate: "Up to 1800 Mbit/s" and "At least 50 TBytes/day". (Note: I don't see how these two figures equate.)

Here is the first big test: [an image](http://m.esa.int/Our_Activities/Telecommunications_Integrated_Applications/EDRS/Europe_s_SpaceDataHighway_relays_first_Sentinel-1_images_via_laser) taken by Sentinel 1A, sent by laser to an EDRS satellite (in geostationary orbit) and beamed down direct to the base station in Germany. ([Hi-res version](http://www.esa.int/var/esa/storage/images/esa_multimedia/images/2016/06/la_reunion_island_via_laser/16013249-1-eng-GB/La_Reunion_Island_via_laser.jpg))

The biggest [advantage](http://m.esa.int/Our_Activities/Telecommunications_Integrated_Applications/EDRS/Applications) of all this is a Sentinel satellite in low earth orbit can pass its information to base with the minimum of delay, even when out of sight of a base station.

Here's a picture of one of the satellite-mounted laser communication terminals:

[image]

(Bigger version of the picture available [here](http://www.esa.int/spaceinimages/Images/2015/06/Laser_communication_terminal).)

Comment: There are two good answers, I chose this one because it describes what's being demonstrated right now. Don't worry about the data rates - maybe they will use multiple wavelengths (fibers can use 100 or more) and certainly some fancy [modulation techniques](http://photonicssociety.org/newsletters/feb09/modulation.pdf) 10 bits/sec per Hz has been demonstrated last year. The beauty of truly free space is that there won't be the same non-linearity and dispersion that even the best silica fiber has. Then there is linear polarization and circular and optical vortices- there are ways to pack packets!

Comment: ...I'm not saying it's all easy, I just mean don't worry about the math right now.

Answer (score 5):

The lunar mission which tested optical communication was [LADEE](http://esc.gsfc.nasa.gov/267/271.html).  The ISS program you're thinking of is [OPALS](http://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/station/research/news/opals_data_rates_soar).  Both tests succeeded, but neither was meant for ongoing operation.  LADEE intentionally impacted the moon, and the US orbital segment of ISS currently uses S and Ku band radio communication through TDRSS.

The next proposed study on laser communication is [LCRD](http://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/tdm/lcrd/overview.html), which hopes to fly on a commercial payload in 2019.

There is also a high probability that the next Mars orbiter will use optical communication.  NASA has been interested in optical communications for  Mars since at least 2008, as shown in [this presentation](http://slideplayer.com/slide/6216963/) from Jim Schier, Chief Architect for NASA’s Space Communications and Navigation Program at NASA Headquarters.  Most recently, in April 2016 a request for information went out concerning this upcoming Mars orbiter, and the awards are due to come out this June, so stay tuned.  Look for lasercomm, solar electric propulsion, a high-res camera, and ground-penetrating radar in the winning proposals.

Comment: Great! Thanks for identifying the two previous demonstrations. It looks like you are focused mainly on NASA, there seems to be a few more space agencies "out there", just counting the terrestrial ones :) Are you releasing the results formally here, or just speculating?