# How will EarthNow LLC obtain its real-time video of Earth?

Tags: earth-observation

The New York Times article [Asteroids and Adversaries: Challenging What NASA Knows About Space Rocks](https://www.nytimes.com/2018/06/14/science/asteroids-nasa-nathan-myhrvold.html) led me to read further about Nathan P. Myhrvold which led me to the interesting This American Life podcast [When Patents Attack!](https://www.thisamericanlife.org/441/when-patents-attack):

> Why would a company rent an office in a tiny town in East Texas, put a nameplate on the door, and leave it completely empty for a year? The answer involves a controversial billionaire physicist in Seattle, a 40 pound cookbook, and a war waging right now, all across the software and tech industries. We take you inside this war, and tell the fascinating story of how an idea enshrined in the US constitution to promote progress and innovation, is now being used to do the opposite.

which then led to the recent Intellectual Ventures press release [EarthNow to deliver real-time video via large satellite constellation](http://www.intellectualventures.com/news/press-releases/earthnow-to-deliver-real-time-video-via-large-satellite-constellation) which then leads to my

**question:** *How will EarthNow LLC obtain video of Earth?*

Will they use [Carbonite](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/26718/12102) perhaps? Or will they just buy and sell video data rights? Or perhaps the way YouTube generates revenue by providing a platform for the posting and viewing of video without generating any locally (except of course for [video #1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lQm-LbSJarQ))